# Show that, in all bases $n$ greater than $3$, the number written as $1331$ is a perfect cube.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that, in all bases $n$ greater than $3$, the number written as $1331$ is a perfect cube.

I was given this question to do and sadly I have no idea where to even begin. Any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: Expand $(1 + x)^3$

Comment: but then how do i proceed after that?

Comment: I'm sorry i should i looked around more instead of directly asking

Comment: @Maths2468, it's ok. Several times I have also asked questions which turned out duplicates later. That frequently happens here. You need not feel ashamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $b$ is the basis we have $b\gt 3$ otherwise we cannot use the digit $3$. One has

$$\overline{1331}_b=b^3+3b^2+3b+1$$

Now remember that $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$ and therefore

$$\overline{1331}_b=(b+1)^3$$

is a perfect cube.

Comment: Thank you it makes complete sense now:)

Answer (score 1):

If the base is $b$ then this number 1331 represents $b^3  + 3b^2 + 3b + 1 = (1+b)^3$.

Comment: OH YEAH that makes sense. You write its base expansion and then just simplified it right?

Comment: Yes, you have to know what the representation means in terms of the base $b$. And recognise special products.